# What scripting language has both ec2 library & easy to use ncurses api?

Tags: api, command-line-interface, amazon-ec2

I'm looking to write a cli replacement for elasticfox. 
Would be nice to use python / ruby / bash or something alike.

This is a side project to make our Ubuntu environment a bit more fun, so as much abstraction as possible - I'm loving it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like Python, there's:

- Several 3rd party EC2 modules: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=ec2&submit=search
- A built-in ncurses library: http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#module-curses
- A nice and powerful ncurses alternative called 'urwid': http://excess.org/urwid/

Answer (score 0):

Or use Perl.

EC2: https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::EC2

Curses: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=curses&mode=module (plenty of modules with different grades of abstraction)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use bash and a curses based dialog program like whiptail or dialog.  The dialog program also has an X equivalent, Xdialog.

This can be useful for very simple, quick and dirty, or POC work.